# HTML split code in different files

Tags: html

I want to remove 2 lines of my HTML code and put them in another html file (ex: index2.html), but those 2 lines must be before `</body>` ends.

How can I put those 2 lines in another html file and keep it working as they was never removed?

The code that I want to move is a popup window.
The code that I move is the line that connects with another site and gives me the popup.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://thesite.com/script.php?id=21940"></script>
```

And the line that I want to remain in original index.html calls that popup from a button:

```
onclick="call_window();"
```

Comment: It is not possible to reply to this in an easy manner without knowing those line. But typically that is _not_ an easy thing to do. It would be _much_ more simply if you would use a server base scripting language for this. Typcially php these days. Then you could simply include the lines without any need for client side javascript.

Comment: I think you not describe your source problem. What want you to reach? what you want with the two lines extracted from your hmtl file?

Comment: yes i got it guys you must know what i want to remove i added the lines that i want to remove.

Comment: In other words, you want to include one html file into another at front-end side, don't you? I know two options to do this: using angularjs and jquery. Are you familiar with them?

Comment: Yes, no i am not i am pretty newbie can you provide any tutorial/example?